# MFC RIbbon - Multiple CMFCRibbonComboBox on the same panel, respond to selectitem action performed on any onComboBox

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon, mfc-feature-pack

I have 2 CMFCRibbonComboBox on the same Panel in a Ribbon- Eg:

```
CMFCRibbonComboBox *individualComputers = 
   new CMFCRibbonComboBox(-1,FALSE, 100, "Individual Computers", -1);

individualComputers->AddItem("Computer 1");
individualComputers->AddItem("Computer 2");
individualComputers->AddItem("Computer 3");
individualComputers->SelectItem(0); 

CMFCRibbonComboBox * groupNames = 
   new CMFCRibbonComboBox (-1, FALSE, 100, "Computer Group Names", -1);

groupNames->AddItem("GROUP 1");
groupNames->AddItem("GROUP 2");
groupNames->AddItem("GROUP 3");
groupNames->SelectItem(0);

CMFCRibbonPanel* pComputerGroups =  cComputerGroups->AddPanel("All Groups"); 
//cComputerGroups is a Category

pComputerGroups->Add(individualComputers);
pComputerGroups->Add(groupNames);
```

The problem is that , when I select "Group 1" in the groupNames comboBox from the UI(USer Interface) , then even "Computer 1" from the group individualComputers is selected. How do I make each combobox group independent of the other? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you didn't want add your combobox to itself `individualComputers->Add(individualComputers);` should perhaps be `pComputerGroups->Add(individualComputers);`

Otherwise your bug is probably elsewhere in your command or updateUI handling code not shown. This is likely as **you are using the same ID of -1 to identify both combo boxes.**

Furthermore there is no overloaded constructor for `CMFCRibbonComboBox` which takes an additional two parameters as you have shown for `groupNames`.

In the future please show actual code which follows [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

**Edit:** Made previously unaddressed comment bold as it is likely to be your remaining issue. Consider using `const UINT CB_COMP_ID = 1;` and `const UINT CB_GROUP_ID = 2;` then you can reference each combo box separately using `CB_COMP_ID` or `CB_GROUP_ID` in the message map etc.

Comment: Made changes suggested. Going ahead will try to adhere to SSCCE.